# react-Beautiful DnD – can only drag last item in droppable container

Tags: reactjs, drag-and-drop

i'm using Beautiful DnD in my React Project and encountering a bug. Only the last Item in a droppable container is draggable. When I click on the other Items, it gives me an "Unable to find draggable with id: id1" warning. Although when I add a new Item, the new Item is also drag'n'droppable.

These are the relevant Code Snippet:
App.js - Droppable Container

```
<DragDropContext onDragEnd={onDragEnd}>
        <div className='flex flex-col items-center h-screen'>
          <Droppable droppableId='upflow' type={'ACTION'}>
            {(provided) => (
              <div
                ref={provided.innerRef}
                {...provided.droppableProps}
                className='flex flex-col justify-end flex-1 text-center action-container'
              >
                {upFlow &&
                  upFlow.map((actionId) => {
                    let action = flow.byId[actionId.id];
                    return (
                      <Action //..A LOT OF PROPS// />
                    );
                  })}
                {provided.placeholder}
              </div>
            )}
          </Droppable>
....
```

Action.js - Draggable Item

```
<Draggable draggableId={actionId.id} index={indexInRenderOrder}>
      {(provided) => (
        <div
          ref={provided.innerRef}
          {...provided.draggableProps}
          className='flex justify-between my-1 overflow-hidden font-bold text-black group'
        >
          {/* onClick={handleMultiSelect} */}
          <div {...provided.dragHandleProps}>
            <MdDragHandle
              size={30}
              className={
                isInMultiSelect
                  ? 'bg-blue-200 h-10 mr-1'
                  : 'h-10 mr-1 bg-white group-hover:bg-blue-200'
              }
            />
          </div>
          //.....more Code//
        </div>
      )}
    </Draggable>
```

Maybe you guys know what is causing it :)

ALSO: Is there another DnD Library that you can recommend that also supports multi drag?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue! For those who struggles with the same problem.

In the `Draggable`, inside the `(provided) => { ... }`, add this line of code before rendering the item:

```
if (typeof provided.draggableProps.onTransitionEnd === "function") {
    queueMicrotask(() => 
        provided.draggableProps.onTransitionEnd?.({
            propertyName: "transform"
        })
    );
 }
```

I based the answer [here](https://github.com/atlassian/react-beautiful-dnd/issues/1662#issuecomment-708538811) (Initially, there was an error) but to avoid the error, I based the solution [here](https://github.com/atlassian/react-beautiful-dnd/issues/1662#issuecomment-844967652)

I can't give a concrete answer as to why this works. I have yet to find out why.